# Instagram does not redirects after sign in

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I have an issue while authenticating Instagram via my application.If the user has not signed in while doing authentication it directs me to Instagram login page after logged in it does not redirect to app even i have given RedirectUrl in my app and it loads Instagram page .Moreover if the user user has already logged in and doing authentication means it redirects to my app and works fine.I have tested this case before and it was working fine but now it is not working.Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's a problem on Instagram's end, they are probably working on a fix right now.

Comment: Thank you for the information