# Instagram does not redirect the user to the app after sign in

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are building an iOS app where users are asked to sign in with Instagram.

The flow is as follows:

1. we open an Instagram login page in a web view,
2. user inputs his login and password,
3. then in most of the cases he is asked to verify his account by getting a code by email or phone and entering it on the next page,
4. after doing so, Instagram app opens in a web view and does not redirect to the app.

I saw a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243807/instagram-does-not-redirects-after-sign-in), but did not find it usefull.

Maybe you have faced such an issue before and can somehow help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: No, it just started working one day – we don't actually know what influenced this.

Comment: In Android we use **WebView** to detect onPageFinished and check the *redirect URL* if it contains "#access_token" it means successful, then start new needed screen. Hope there is something similar to iOS

Answer (score 0):

This is probably ancient history by now, but in case someone else is stuck with the same problem you may want to have a look at your universal-links.

Supporting universal links for the `redirect_uri` turned out to cause sporadic failures for us.